# Logitech k480 key not working

Tags: keyboard, wireless-keyboard

I am using the keyboard with a Windows 10 computer. The key to the left of the digit 1 - the tilde / backtick key is not working. When I press it nothing is being typed.

I tested the keyboard on Android and it is not working there either.

Any suggestions on how to fix the issue?

Update: I ended up remapping ` to be the Alt Gr key using KeyTweak.

Comment: Sounds like the keyboard is bad. That typically means replace it.

Comment: @Appleoddity It could be some setting related to layout or something though. The keyboard had that issue from the start.

Comment: Simply go to a keyboard test website. That will tell you if the keypress is detected or not.

Comment: Since nothing is printed on the screen those tests will probably fail.

Comment: Have you checked? Those tools don’t work like you are describing at all. Mapping has absolutely nothing to do with if a scan code is generated or not. Those tools show the the codes being generated. If the button is pushed it will show up, period.

Comment: Yes, I tried one of them and it didn't detect it. Do you have a specific one in mind?

Comment: I tried 4 of them and neither of them detected that key.